# Calculation of product of all coprimes of number less than itself

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms, prime-factorization

Is there any fast way or formula to calculate product of all coprimes of a number less than itself?

How can we do it without finding all coprimes manually?

Note : I have to find actually (product) modulo (the given number).

Comment: coprimes does it mean prime,

Comment: Nope coprime meant gcd(n,coprime) = 1

Comment: It seems hard .

Comment: Well that's why I posted it here(there are great mathematicians here) well there is midnight here in India and now I am about to sleep so could not thought properly myself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OEIS has this as [A001783](https://oeis.org/A001783) where they call it the "phi-torial." They cite Apostol, "Introduction to Analytic Number Theory" in which it is an exercise to show that
$$
\prod_{1\le i<n, \gcd(i,n)=1} i = n^{\varphi(n)}\prod_{d\mid n}
\left(\frac{d!}{d^d}\right)^{\mu(n/d)}
$$
where $\varphi$ is Euler's totient and $\mu$ is the Möbius function.

This gives you a formula that doesn't require "finding all coprimes." It probably doesn't qualify as a "fast way" to compute the exact value, since it requires computing several factorials, but it may allow you to efficiently get an approximate result e.g. using Stirling's approximation.

This is also referred to as the "Gauss factorial" and is the diagonal of OEIS [A216919](https://oeis.org/A216919) where you can find additional references.

Comment: Thanks this is great input .But I will wait for some more time if someone posts fast approach than this before accepting it.

Comment: What will happen if we have to calculate modulo w.r.t the given number there